# How to check the depth of an object?

Tags: javascript, object, recursion

I'm working on a permissions system with variable depth; depending on the complexity of a page, there could be more or less levels. I searched StackOverflow to find if this has been asked before, couldn't find it.

If I have this object:

```
{foo:{bar:{baz : 'baa'}}}
```

I need it to return 3, it has 3 levels to it.

With this object:

```
{abc: 'xyz'}
```

It would have to be 1.

This is what I have so far:

```
utils.depthOf = function(object, level){
    // Returns an int of the deepest level of an object
    level = level || 1;

    var key;
    for(key in object){
        if (!object.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

        if(typeof object[key] == 'object'){
            level++;
            level = utils.depthOf(object[key], level);
        }
    }

    return level;
}
```

The problem is it counts sister elements too. It's actually not getting depth, it's counting all members of an object.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Well, here you go buddy, a function that does exactly what you need!

```
utils.depthOf = function(object) {
    var level = 1;
    for(var key in object) {
        if (!object.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

        if(typeof object[key] == 'object'){
            var depth = utils.depthOf(object[key]) + 1;
            level = Math.max(depth, level);
        }
    }
    return level;
}
```

A lot easier than we thought it would be. The issue was how it was incremented, it shouldn't have been recursively adding, rather getting the bottom-most and adding one, then choosing the max between two siblings.

Comment: What is the argument "level" in this function ?

Comment: It would be called by saying `utils.depthOf({})` - the second parameter is only used for recursion, which is why the second line is saying "level equals level if level isn't false, if level is false, level is one"

Comment: That aside, this function doesn't actually work. If there are sister elements, it counts them as depth rather than "width." - I'm still working on that.

Comment: +2 okay :) If I want to check dom dept of html element i.e. document. How do I call this function ?

Comment: You'll run into a maximum call stack problem, most likely. The `document` object is really, really deep. That's literally a `stack_overflow` - but you would call it by just `utils.depthOf(document)`

Comment: working wrong for situation `{test: [{...}, {...}]}`

Comment: @nktssh that's because it's not doing a thorough enough job type checking. Arrays are objects. You would want to add another expression to the conditional using `Array.isArray`

Comment: "here you go buddy" talking to yourself lmao

Answer (score 7):

This old question was recently resurrected and I don't see any answers as simple as this one (to be fair, this uses techniques not available when the question was written):

```js
const objectDepth = (o) =>
  Object (o) === o ? 1 + Math .max (-1, ... Object .values(o) .map (objectDepth)) : 0

console .log (objectDepth ({foo: {bar: {baz: 'baa'}}}))
console .log (objectDepth ({abc: 'xyz'}))
```

This, like most answers here, will fail when the input object is cyclic.  An answer that addresses that limitation would require much more sophistication.

Comment: doesn't get much more simple than that!

Comment: This should be the new expected answer. The one using a for loop is outdated

Comment: @talweissler: Thanks.  But I prefer the answer from Mulan, which also handles cyclic objects.  It's not as simple as this one, but it's a complete function, where this one is partial.

Answer (score 1):

Back from the dead! Throwing my solution into the mix -

```js
function depth (t, mem = new Set)
{ if (mem.has(t))
    return Infinity
  else switch (mem.add(t), t?.constructor)
  { case Object:
    case Array:
      return 1 + Math.max
       ( -1
       , ...Object
           .values(t)
           .map(_ => depth(_, mem))
       )
    default:
      return 0
  }
}

console.log(depth({a: {b: {c: "z"}}}))   // 3
console.log(depth({a: "z"}))             // 1
console.log(depth({}))                   // 0
console.log(depth("z"))                  // 0
console.log(depth({a: [{b: "z"}]}))      // 3

const a = []
a[0] = a
console.log(depth(a))                    // Infinity
```

Comment: Nice!  I didn't try to do it, but simply assumed cyclic objects would be fairly difficult.  This proves me entirely wrong.

Comment: ha, i don't think i would've bothered to attempt it until reading your comment about it. it ended up being easier than i thought, too :D

Answer (score 0):

We can use the reg:

```js
function getHowManyLevel(obj) {
  let res = JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/[^{|^}]/g, '')
  while (/}{/g.test(res)) {
    res = res.replace(/}{/g, '')
  }
  return res.replace(/}/g, '').length
}
```

Comment: I know let and minify do not play friendly together.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, if you wanna keep it short:

```
function maxDepth(object) {
    if (typeof object !== "object" || object === null) {
        return 0;
    }

    let values = Object.values(object);

    return (values.length && Math.max(...values.map(value => maxDepth(value)))) + 1;
}
```

Comment: This would give a depth of `1` for `{}`, which presumably should be `0`.  Maybe `return values .length ? 1 + Math .max ( /* ... */) : 0` ?

Comment: My thought was that primitive values should have depth 0, thus `{}` depth 1 and so on, but that's just a matter of normalisation. Thing is, `{}` may be empty, but is has a depth, you can put something inside.

Comment: And `{}` should have the same depth as `{foo:"bar"}`

Comment: I guess it entirely depends on your notion of depth.  This is a pretty old question and I don't know if the OP is still around, but my thought was that it was equivalent to the number of nodes in the longest path to a nested property.

Answer (score 0):

I used a dirty but efficient way :

The good point is that there is no Regex in it, because regex is costly in process time

```js
getObjectDepth = (object) => {
      // json to array of parenthesis array: ['{','{','}','}',]
      let string = JSON.stringify(object)
          .split('')
          .filter(char => ['{', '}'].includes(char) );

      let currentDepth = 0;
      let maxDepth = 0;
      string.forEach(char => {
          if (char === '{') currentDepth++;
          if (char === '}') currentDepth--;
          if (currentDepth > maxDepth) maxDepth = currentDepth;
      });

      return maxDepth
}
```

It will only work if the object has no parenthesis in a string value though.