# Convert Javascript object reference in dot notation into string

Tags: javascript, string

Given a JS Object:

```
var obj = {
            a: {
               b: {
                  c: {}
               }
            }
         };
```

How can i convert `obj.a.b` into string `"obj.a.b"` to count how many objects (3) have been used? In this case `obj.a.b`: 3. I have tried `''+obj.a.b`, `uneval()`, `toSource()`, `toString()`, `for...in`, `Object.key().length` but it is not what i want to know.
I imagine it's not possible... but not sure.

For example why i want:

```
function h (o) {
    let a = o.split('.');
    if (a.length > 2) {
        alert('not allowed'); // because obj.a.b > 2
        return;
    } else {
        // because obj.a == 2 -> ok. process with obj.a ..
    }
}

h(obj.a.b);
```

Comment: So you want to be able to type `obj.a.b` and get back `"obj.a.b"`?

Comment: `obj.a.b` what do you mean by that? Do you have some code that accesses that? Do you just want to find how many levels deep `b` is? Where does that come from and also, why do you want to count references?

Comment: @Mike: Yes, exactly

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Vld: no, i dont want to find the levels deep of  `b` or the source of `obj.a.b` like `JSON.stringify()` etc...

Comment: @hg95 OK, but _why_ do you want to do that? Just curiosity or are you trying to solve something? Because if it's the latter, it does indeed seem like an XY problem.

Comment: you can use something like JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/\}|\{|'/gi, ''); then replace the ": to . and u will get what you want

Comment: You could do some crazy shenanigans with [Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/get) to get at least each property access but it would definitely be some shenanigans. Not something you'd want for real-world code.

Comment: @Vld: i have updated with example

Comment: Doesn't explain why exactly you want to do that. It's possible to do it. The ways range from a bit off to a bit unwieldy but overall doable. Avoiding it would be vastly easier, though and it sounds to me like you are trying to solve something in a roundabout way, perhaps there is a better solution.

Answer (score -2):

A solution on how to find the depth of an object has already been provided under [How to check the depth of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523951/how-to-check-the-depth-of-an-object).

If you just need to convert it to a string form you could

```
> JSON.stringify(obj)
"{"a":{"b":{"c":{}}}}"
```

Comment: Again, I don't think OP is looking for the _total depth_ of the object nesting but check how many levels deep _specifically_ a particular value retrieval is.